# npa201 i2c address change

Tags: stm32, i2c

I need to change an  i2c address of an amphenol nova sensor NPA201 (pressure) using an stm32F407-discovery board.

An application note provided by manufacturer raises some questions.
According to the table, the one must set cpu's i2c module to master-receiver mode, and immediately send a byte to sensor. Is it even possible to do so?

May be i need to read reference manual one more time, buy as far as i know  such situation is not described there.

Has anybody done the changing address procedure  before?

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gU8Qc.jpg)

Comment: It is normal I2C operation. No magic or tricks here. learn something about I2C and everything will become obvious. Read about the "REPEAT START".

Comment: @PeterJ_01 Thank you. I know about the repeated start, but the table clearly states that no repeated start is required. So i still do not know is it possible or it is just a misleading table.

Comment: You just do not understand this document. It shows only dthe dataflow, not the i2c details. For them read the datasheet

Answer (score 0):

Information for changing the address of the sensor can be found [here](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwivsJfEorHWAhUJKFAKHdFhABMQFggzMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.arduino.cc%2Findex.php%3Faction%3Ddlattach%3Btopic%3D492345.0%3Battach%3D220746&usg=AFQjCNEJ9DJ4Vgf7t5bHuCQiZvJOpJA_KQ) Please note you can only change it three times. The default i2c address is 0x27.

Comment: Thank you, i've seen this. And all my questions raises from this appnote. I know about the repeated start, but the table clearly states that no repeated start is required. So i still do not know is it possible or it is just a misleading table.

Comment: It does not say that :). It just explained it from the app point of view where stops and starts are implicit. More detailed information you have in the datasheet.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 Thanks:)